# In ADF 11g ApplicationModule error while submitting form

Tags: oracle-adf

1.after inserting a record in db properly ,im trying to insert another record(after clicking save button ) but it giving on error like ," 
Attribute DoctorId in AppModule.DoctorEOView1 is required" ,and its why its giving how can i solve it

2.i like to get a attribut value from db and  show this attribute value increment by  one in ui ,in empty form as default value
how to do it in ADF 11 g

Answer (score 0):

1 - this is because your DoctorId  is empty and marked as requiered.
2 - read about the DBSequence data type in ADF BC.
More:
https://pinboard.in/search/u:OracleADF?query=DBSequence

Comment: @ Shay Shmeltzer tx and im showing a empty form for registration purpose in this form i hav registerId as a column ,and i wanna show a default value for registerId and it must be incremented by 1.When i use sequence its giving wrong value,my last record in table the value of the registerId is 4 but if i use db sequence it showing 22,why it is like that.